# Text not showing in print preview

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'll try to print my web page but in print preview, it's not showing any text

try to add media print style but still nothing

[image: After Print]

My HTML code

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);
 body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
 }
 </style>
   <style type="text/css">
  @media print and (color){
    body {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      print-color-adjust: exact;
   }

  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Nota</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap2.css">
</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
     <h1>
       <a href="https://riyadhaqiqah.com/">
      <img src="riyadh.png">
       </a>
     </h1>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
     <h1>INVOICE</h1>
     <h1><small>NOTA : PBSAN1908381</small></h1>
   </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4>From: <a href="#">Riyadh Aqiqah</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>
                    Komplek, Jl. Mawar Raya Jl. Raya Harapan Kita No.27A<br>
                    Bencongan, Kec. Karawaci <br>
                    Tangerang, Banten 15810 <br>
                    0821-5199-9910 <br>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-2 text-right">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4>To : <a href="#"> Agus Mina</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>
                    Kp. Kudang Rt/Rw 04/09, <br>
                    Ds. Cibiru Wetang Kec. Cileunyi - Bandung (Warung Amel, sebelah isi ulang air Novita) <br>
                    <a href="">0852-1342-6441</a> <br>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- / end client details section -->

           <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><h4>NO</h4></th>
            <th><h4>URAIAN</h4></th>
            <th><h4>HARGA SATUAN</h4></th>
            <th><h4>QTY</h4></th>
            <th><h4>JUMLAH</h4></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Tipe A Betina + Masak</td>
            <td class="text-right"><span style="float: left;">Rp </span>1,100,000</td>
             <td class="text-right">1</td>
              <td class="text-right"><span style="float: left;">Rp </span>1,100,000</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

  <div class="row text-right">
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-8">
    <p>
     <strong>
      Diskon     : <br>
      Uang Muka  : <br>
      Kekurangan : <br>
      Total      : <br>
     </strong>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2">
    <strong>
     <span style="float: left;">Rp </span>0 <br>
     <span style="float: left;">Rp </span>1,650,000 <br>
     <span style="float: left;">Rp </span>0 <br>
     <span style="float: left;">Rp </span>1,650,000 <br>
    </strong>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
     <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4>Paypal details</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
       <p>tahirtaous@live.com</p>
      <!--  <p>Bank Name</p>
       <p>SWIFT : --------</p>
       <p>Account Number : --------</p>
       <p>IBAN : --------</p> -->
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here's my fiddle , it's weird on fiddle the text showing up.
if anyone can explain and help me.
I really don't know why this happened.

https://jsfiddle.net/anggi404/2L4pcsa7/1/

Comment: I have tried your jsfiddle, print preview works fine

Comment: It's weird , on fiddle print preview works fine . but on my local project it's not showing any text .

Comment: It works fine for me: Mac/Firefox/Print to PDF.  I'm wondering if it's a browser or print driver issue.

Comment: Yeah it's browser issue i guess , coz try use firefox it's works fine.
Thanks all for answering my question :)

Comment: works fine may be you browser not updated..

Answer (score 0):

Noted that this is an old question but it may help someone out there.
This may have something to do with your custom loaded font.

Try to add something similar if the printed font isn't of too much importance.

In the example below I only target the body but feel free to change this as you see fit of course.

```css
@media print {
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
}
```

Surely there's a way to load in custom fonts in a print but this may help someone get going.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Working on linux, never have a print problem. BUT, in some tests under Windows, the text to print doesnt show in preview. Same problem as you. The problem is that: the font seems loading few seconds after the print dialog appers. The solution is send the window.print() command two seconds after the load of the page.

```
setTimeout(window.print, 2000);
```